# How to stop this while loop from crashing the browser?

Tags: javascript, html

I have to use a while loop for this project, I know a for loop is probably easier but just the way this has to be done.

The function needs to take user input (1-5) based on how many job duties the user wants to see and then call the array number (0-4), so if they say 3 job duties, array items 0,1,2 need to be printed. This is what I have so far and it keeps crashing the browser, not sure how to control the loop and make sure it prints out all the array values instead of just one.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       function jobduties() {
       var x = document.getElementById("input").value;
       var y = x-1;
       var duties = ["Sales", "Customer Service", "Management", "Driving", "Cleaning"]; 
       while (x>=0) {
       var y
       document.getElementById("print").innerHTML=duties[y];
       break;
       }       
     }
</script>

<form>
```

Clickto see  job duties for this job.

Job duties here

Comment: why are you asking here instead of your teacher?

Comment: I asked him, he didn't really help, just told me I had to deprecate the variable but I can't figure out how to

Comment: You are not incrementing the value of x, therefore x is always zero.
add the line:
    
    x++;

in the while loop.

Comment: @Pmurphy The word is "decrement", not "deprecate".

Answer (score 1):

Inside the while loop increment the value of x

Your x is always the same hence the condition always satisfies hence the loop does not break

Answer (score 1):

1 - your x never decrease so you stock in this forever loop.
2 - you don't need a local y inside the while.

```
 function jobduties() {
   var x = document.getElementById("input").value;
   var y = 0;
   var duties = ["Sales", "Customer Service", "Management", "Driving", "Cleaning"]; 
   while (x > y) {

   document.getElementById("print").innerHTML=duties[y];
   y++;

   }       
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution for you, which has just been tested:

```js
function jobduties() {
  document.getElementById("print").innerHTML = ""
  var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("input").value);
  var y = 0
  var duties = ["Sales", "Customer Service", "Management", "Driving", "Cleaning"];
  while (y < x) {
    document.getElementById("print").innerHTML = document.getElementById("print").innerHTML + "<br>" + duties[y];
    y = y + 1;
  }
}
```

```html
Number of duties:
<input type="Number" id="input">
<button onclick="jobduties()">Click me</button>
<p id="print"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, get rid of recreating y in the loop, since it has been already created. Secondly, your while loop is infinite since x is either always more than 0 or less than it, consequently, your while loop will either run and become infinite or will just be skipped. To solve your problem with crash of your while loop, try to increment x.

Let's suppose i=x=3(user input), we will be iterating until it reaches 0 by subtracting 1 each step in the loop. After each step we will be printing i, which will give us 3,2,1

```
//Your code with input goes here
for(var i=x; i=0;i--){
document.Write(i);
}
```